# Javascript SDK connect() function not working in chrome

Tags: soundcloud

Am attempting to model my code after the example here: http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/connecting.html#

It works in firefox, but not in chrome.  In chrome, the soundcloud popup shows up correctly, and I can sign in (returning to sc-connect.html), but then the window won't close.  Upon closer inspection, there's a javascript error because window.opener is null.  I wonder if it has to do with localhost uri?  The example at the link above works in both firefox and chrome.  Any ideas?  My code below:

```
SC.initialize({client_id:'my_client_id', redirect_uri:'http://localhost:3000/sc-connect.html'});

$('button').click(function(){
  SC.connect(function () {
    console.log('made it');
  }
}
```

My sc-connect.html page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
      <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Redirect URI on soundcloud for this app: http://localhost:3000/sc-connect.html

Comment: ok, so after some more testing, the code above (after fixing missing paren) works in firefox, safari, and chromium, but not chrome (even in icognito w/ no extensions)...not sure what could be different, esp. between chromium and chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a strange bug in Chrome which is caused by installing the SoundCloud app from the Chrome App Store. Bizarre, I know.

A workaround is instead of using `window.opener`, push the oauth token into LocalStorage or SessionStorage and have the opener window listen to the [Storage event](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#event-storage).

Comment: wow - that's most definitely the problem...uninstalled soundcloud as an app on chrome, and it now works!

thanks so much for validating the problem I was seeing!  currently implementing the local storage solution - thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Hi Jeffthink. Have you had any luck implementing a solution to this? JS is not my strength and I was wondering if you (or anyone else) could elaborate on the suggested solution. thanks!

Comment: @afxjzs if you're having specific problems with using localstorage or the storage events, you could ask your own question!

Comment: i have VERY limited experience with both, so i don't have one specific question. I was just hoping/asking `jeffthink` to post his solution once he found. If I solve it myself and it's still not answered, i'll post it here.  This is a **Chrome** bug and not a **Soundcloud** bug, correct?

Comment: @afxjzs Yes, it's a problem with Chrome and we've tried raising it with their developers a couple of times but still aren't getting any love in return...

Comment: This bug crops up with all sorts of apps - I had a similar problem with Trello whilst using their JS API with Trello installed as a Chrome app.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a couple of closing brackets in your example code. Other than that, nothing appears obviously wrong with your example. I copied and pasted your sc-connect.html and used it with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
      SC.initialize({
          client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/connect/sc-callback.html'
      });

      $('button').click(function(){
          SC.connect(function() {
              SC.get('/me', function(data) {
                  $('#name').text(data.username);
              });
          });
      });
  });

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Connect</button>
  <p>
    Hello There, <span id="name"></span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This works for me in Firefox and Chrome. Let me know if the that helps.

Comment: hey paul - thanks for the response, and sorry for missing paren (was translating from coffeescript)...see my comment above about it working in basically all other browsers...not sure what (setting?) to look to change in chrome to try and get it to work...any thoughts?  in meantime, will just use firefox

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
    <title>Connect with SoundCloud</title> 

</head>
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
    <b style="text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.opener.SC.connectCallback.call(this); </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```